# Adding a running count to dataset in MS Access, by ID code

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a dataset with multiple records per ID code (`APInumber`).

I want to create a new field that counts each record for a given `APInumber` so that I can use that query to only pull the max (most recent) record.

I think it might be something along these lines:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/94397

Desired Output

```
APINumber  |  Count
42227      |   1
42227      |   2
42229      |   1
42310      |   1
```

But I'm at a loss for even how to begin. Basically I need to reference the cell above and I'm not sure how to do that in Access SQL.

My other queries group by API, so if there are multiple records, it will give me an incorrect grouping. I'm hoping to just add some type of numbering to be able to identify the last record for each API in the table - from what I've seen, the last record is typically the most updated (from referencing with hard-copies of PDFs). There is no identifier verifying it's the most updated though.

In excel, I would do the following:

```
API (col A)  |   Count (col B)
42227        |   = if(a2=a1,b1+1,1) = 1
42227        |   = if(a3=a2,b2+1,1) = 2
42229        |   = if(a4=a3,b3+1,1) = 1
42310        |   = if(a5=a4,b4+1,1) = 1
```

Help?

Comment: How are the multiple records for an APINumber ordered?  Is there another field that identifies the max or most recent record?

Comment: No, there's no identifier on the most recent record, it is just a duplicate APInumber. From what I've looked at, I think the most recent is always the second (or last) record on the table, so I'm hoping to be able to pull in the max of the API count for my other queries to point it to that one. I can get a count of API to flag which APInumbers have more than one record, but that's all I have so far.

Comment: Can you add an autonumber field to force an order to the data?  I don't see how to do what you're asking without another field to identify the record.  Even if you had a way to flag the "last" record (which doesn't seem to actually be defined), how would you identify that record to the next query?

Comment: If all you need is the max (most recent) record then your desired output is not correct. What is the purpose of returning API #42227 with count = 1?

Comment: so I tried the article and it does create a running count but NOT a partitioned running count which is what you need.  Also that count would also have to be reset to 0 by running a macro before every use.  So I tried it as a method of adding a row number that you can then use in a join to do aggregation and get your running count but the row number doesn't persist appropriately.  you need an additional field to get this figured out.  As @DonGeorge suggests I would recommend adding an autonumber field then the task becomes a lot more trivial.

Comment: I added some detail to the original question that might help.

Comment: If you can autonumber the table it's easy.  If not, you might try a query that groups on APINumber and select Max(fieldname) or Last(fieldname) for all the other data fields.  That will give you a result that has only 1 row per APINumber and associated data that might be representative.